# Android: how to get data from Runnable using postDelayed method?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, runnable

I am using Runnable to get data from GPS device, but sometimes cannot get data from outside although value inside always has value.

*BaseSevice.java*

```
protected Handler mHandler = new Handler();
protected volatile String mRawLine;
protected Runnable mReadDeviceDataTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        int delay = Constants.DEFAULT_GET_DATA_INTERVAL;        //interval = 100ms
        if (deviceType() == DeviceSupport.GPS) {
            delay = Constants.GPS_GET_DATA_INTERVAL;            //interval = 10ms
        }

        if (mDevice == null) {
            mHandler.postDelayed(mReadDeviceDataTask, delay);
            return;
        }
        try {
            if (mInputStream.available() > 0) {
                mRawLine = "some data here get from GPS device";        //data got continuously & many lines
            }
        } catch (IOException ioEx) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Can not read lines from socket", ioEx);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error while read from input stream", e);
        }
        mHandler.postDelayed(mReadDeviceDataTask, delay);
    }
};
```

*GPSService.java* extends BaseService

`public String getmRawLine() {
        Log.e("debug","return mRawLine:" + mRawLine);
        return mRawLine;//<--- sometimes there is no value
    }`

Comment: You can use custom broadcast receiver or Interface as callback mechanism

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki We cannot use broadcast because of sending big data every 10ms. We tried to use interface but not success.